# I can't use resources on fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I use Fullcalendar from **fullcalendar** or **fullcalendar-reactwrapper**, in each case I can't set resources, just doesn't work.

I use

```
resources = {
        { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
        { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
}
```

or

```
resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
]
```

still not working :'(
where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, FoxFr. Can you give more details about the problem, so people can be most effective when helping you out? Especially how exactly you try to use your code snippet would help

Comment: As noted in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-data), using resources requires the extra [Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) plugin which, depending on your circumstances, you may need to purchase a [licence](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/license) for. Have you included the Scheduler code in your project? Have you checked your licence status?

Comment: P.S. The second of your definitions of `resources` above is correct (again, as per the relevant [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-array). The first one is not even valid JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You check with this:

```
resources: [ 
 { id: '1', title: 'Event Title 1' },
 { id: '2', title:'Event Title 2' },
 { id: '3', title: 'Event Title 3' } 
],
```

For more, you check, working and tested example here:

[Resources with fullcalendar](https://therichpost.com/open-bootstrap-modal-popup-event-click-fullcalendar)

Comment: Despite the comments I already posted before  you answered, you appear to have  entirely missed the point that this requires the scheduler plugin to be installed in order to work. I would guess that is OP's problem. There's nothing wrong with their definition of the resources array (at least their second one anyway)

Comment: Heyn thanks for your help, now i understand why isn't possible to use, le version use from npm is >3.0 and on your example 1.9

Comment: @FoxFr you're confusing the fullCalendar version with the Scheduler version I think. At the time of writing, the latest version of fullCalendar is 3.9.0, the latest version of Scheduler is 1.9.4. I'll repeat one more time (since no-one appears to be paying any attention): for this to work you need to include the Scheduler files in your page, and acquire the appropriate licence. Scheduler is a separate extension to fullCalendar, and is not included by default. The concept of Resources only exists in the Scheduler, and not in the main fullCalendar package.

Comment: ADyson , i understand much better now, about the resources from Scheduler plan